# Injecting view into div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I can't help feel this is wrong way to put a view on a screen(without refresh) upon button click. I'm injecting a view when I click a button through jquery. My problem is it doesn't work all that good on IE and Im using bootstrap so when i go to minimize/make the screen smaller, the responsive comes in but another navbar is appearing right over the injected view, so I have 2 navbars when the screen is small. Is there a complete another way to do this? A more efficient way to call an action in the controller and have a view injected? Thanks.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function ViewMyTutorials() {
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    $.get('@Url.Action("MyTutorials", "Account")', function (result) {

        $("#TutorialInjectionId").html(result);
    });
}
```

```
   <div id="TutorialInjectionId"> 

   </div>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the approach.  If your nav bars are sitting on top of each other when the screen is smaller you probably have a CSS issue.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Like @endyourif said, there's probably something wrong with the CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This AJAX approach is correct. I can't see anything wrong with it. I suspect that you have some CSS/HTML problem, nothing to do with the jQuery AJAX approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the following article, they do very similar to what you doing. This will either boost your confidence if you doing it right, or you will find ideas on how to do it better/the other way...

- [ASP.NET MVC – PartialView with Ajax](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/asp-net-mvc-partialview-with-ajax/)
- [ASP.NET MVC Partial View and Ajax “real world” example](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-and-ajax-real-world-example/)

Hope this helps